# unittests work from command line but not pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, python-unittest

I'm writing some unit tests that I'd like to debug in pycharm. Debugging works just fine. However, if I want to run the tests outside of debug mode, I get:

```
C:\Users\my_name\Miniconda3\envs\feature-extraction\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\_jb_unittest_runner.py" --path D:/projects/A2TD/feature_extraction/tests/reconstruction/test_misc.py

Testing started at 5:04 PM ...

Ran 1 test in 0.002s
Launching unittests with arguments python -m unittest D:/projects/A2TD/feature_extraction/tests/reconstruction/test_misc.py in D:/

FAILED (errors=1)

...
...
    module = __import__(module_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test_misc'
```

However, I am able to get them to run the tests in the command line with:

```
"C:\Users\my_name\Miniconda3\envs\feature-extraction\python.exe" "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\_jb_unittest_runner.py" --path D:/projects/A2TD/feature_extraction/tests/reconstruction/test_misc.py
```

OR this:

```
python -m unittest D:/projects/A2TD/feature_extraction/tests/reconstruction/test_misc.py
```

You will notice that both of the above commands are copied and pasted directly from the PyCharm run output where the error occurs.

These commands work when run from **any location** within the top level project.

I am using unittest with default run configurations which are automatically populated on first run, for example:

[image]

With a standard project structure like:

```
project_folder
|
|- top_level_package/
|   |
|   |- __init__.py
|   |- sub_packages/ (containing modules)
|   
|-tests/
    |- __init__.py
    |- package_to_test/
         |
         |- __init__.py
         |- test_module1.py
         |- test_module2.py
```

#### Question:

How do I get unit tests to run in PyCharm outside of debug mode? Obviously I could just run them in debug mode, but then I'd have to remove all of my breakpoints.

Comment: Have you tried pressing the green "run" button instead of the "debug" button using the same run configuration? It should work provided the test follow [the discoverability rules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#test-discovery). If you get [the patterns right](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dataspell/run-debug-configuration-python-unit-test.html#1) the IDE should take care of the rest. (I've only used pytest which has different rules from unitest.)

Comment: Yes, the green button (or CTRL+ALT+F10) is what I mean by "running the tests outside of debug mode"

Comment: What's strange is the part of `_jb_unittest_runner.py` if you're executing on the command line it should just be `python.exe -m unittest test_file.py` I don't see why invoking the IDE (or your separate command-line run) should use the IDE's `unittest_runner.py` since what you want is for this to execute directly on the Python interpreter. Try the radio button that says "costum" instead and it should work. I think that by choosing the `module` radio button you're relinquishing control to PyCharm that the test should be called using the IDE's debugger.

Answer (score 0):

my approach has been to rename   package_to_test  to  package_to_test_t
After it pycharm with default params starts to resolve the package names.

To run tests on command line  I usually add in unittest  classes before importing  my packages (need to check number of os.path.dirname()  calls depending the directory levels of your test.

```
script_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
projroot_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(script_directory))
sys.path.extend([os.path.join(projroot_directory, 'top_level_package')])


project_folder
|
|- top_level_package/
|   |
|   |- __init__.py
|   |- sub_packages/ (containing modules)
|   
|-tests/
    |- __init__.py
    |- package_to_test_t/
         |
         |- __init__.py
         |- test_module1.py
         |- test_module2.py
```